# How to Change 404 page title

Tags: customization, urls, page-template, 404-error

i have try many methods after searching on internet but unable to ramove Nothing Found from my 404 page title
how to do it please help me

even i have us this in my 404 page header

`if( is_404() ) echo '404 message goes here | ';
else wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );`

i also ramove php title function and five their my own header but still not changing why ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use the `wp_title` filter hook:

```
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title = 'ADD 404 TITLE TEXT HERE';
    }
    // You can do other filtering here, or
    // just return $title
    return $title;
}
// Hook into wp_title filter hook
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

This will play nicely with other Plugins (e.g. SEO Plugins), and will be relatively forward-compatible ([changes to document title are coming soon](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18548)).

**EDIT**

If you need to override an SEO Plugin filter, you probably just need to add a lower *priority* to your `add_filter()` call; e.g. as follows:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title', 11 );
```

The default is `10`. Lower numbers execute *earlier* (e.g. *higher* priority), and higher numbers execute *later* (e.g. *lower* priority). So, assuming your SEO Plugin uses the default priority (i.e. `10`), simply use a number that is 11 or higher.

Comment: Thanks that was not changing because of my seo plugin but thanks for response :)
But Now i Have one more problem 
my 404 page gives 404 header response how can i change that ?

Comment: The SEO Plugin is almost certainly using the `wp_title` filter. If you need to override it, add a *priority* to your `add_filter()` call. See answer update.

Comment: Adding a higher priority did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

### WordPress 4.4 and up

The accepted answer no longer works as `wp_title` is deprecated in WordPress 4.4 and up ([see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/#div-comment-1076)). We must now use the [document_title_parts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) filter hook instead.

Here is the accepted answer rewritten to use `document_title_parts`.

```
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title_parts ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title_parts['title'] = 'ADD 404 TITLE TEXT HERE';
    }

    return $title_parts;
} 

// Hook into document_title_parts
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if they changed anything in WP 6.4? Can't get it to work. This code goes into `functions.php`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine with the twenty eleven theme:

```
if ( is_404() ) { 
  echo __('Nothing Found','mytheme')
}
```

So the title code looks like the following:

```
<title>
<?php 

global $page, $paged;

if ( is_404() ) { 
  echo __('Nothing Found | ','mytheme');
}
else {
  wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
} 

?>
</title>
```

Comment: I **strongly recommend** always outputting `<title>` text using the `wp_title()` function, either by passing an argument, or using the `wp_title` filter hook, so that the code plays nicely with other Plugins that attempt to modify `<title>` text.

Comment: Thanks that was not changing because of my seo plugin but thanks for response :)

Comment: But Now i Have one more problem my 404 page gives 404 header response how can i change that ?